# Reading friends data using C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am playing around with C# SDK and want to be able to read the info of my friends - like likes, profile pic, about me, feed etc. Is it possible?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to use PowerShell and http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com. That way it's just Get-FBFriend at the command-line.